# Как брать время с Интернета для Arduino?

Tags: время, arduino

Есть Arduino nano. К ней будет подключаться пьезоизлучатель (пищалка) нужно что бы пищалка срабатывала в определенное время. Время нужно брать с интернета. Как это сделать и что для этого нужно?

Comment: 1 - нужно подключение к интернету (соответствующий модуль для этого - ethernet или wifi), 2 - нужен модуль часов реального времени. Возможно два в одном - например ESP8266 или ESP32 (в принципе если есть одна из этих плат, то Arduino уже не нужно, по крайней мере для таких простых задач как ваша). Вкратце - периодически подключаетесь к какому-то из серверов NTP, получаете время, подстраиваете часы в модуле реального времени.

Comment: В принципе, если девайс к точности не критичен, то достаточно и просто модуля часов реального времени. Даже если за полгода убежит на 10сек, может быть не страшно.

Comment: Я так понимаю Ardyino не нужна нужен модуль? Можно какую ту статью по этой теме? Искал в интернете что то не особо.

Comment: Задачу внятно сформулируйте пожалуйста, тогда и решение будет точнее